# Why my telegram bot "callback_query" doesn't work?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

Sorry, I would like to know why my telegram bot is not responding to my callback_query. I feel like I did everything correctly but I really don't understand where the error is.

edit:
When I click on the message button, it should send me the callback_data, which is read by the callback_query, but this doesn't happen, why?

### How I set the query variables.

```
//callback
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

$callback = $update['callback_query'];
$callbackUser = $callback['from']['username'];
$callbackID = $callback['id'];
$callbackChatID = $callback['from']['id'];
$callbackData = $callback['data'];
```

### Small if to see if it works.

```
if ($callbackData == 'testo') {
  SMG($ChatID, "funziona");
}
```

### Button to send the callback_data.

```
$minersBtn = [[["text" => "$miningBtn", "callback_data" => "$miningStatus"],["text" => "Indietro⬅️", "callback_data" => "testo"]]];
```

Comment: did you encode is as json?

Comment: Yes, I did it is the variable $update

Comment: i mean you need to `json_encode(["inline_keyboard" => $minersBtn])`, and that will be the keyboard. try it out

Comment: ```function SIkey($ChatID, $text, $keyboard){
  $BTN = [
    "inline_keyboard" => $keyboard,
  ];
  $BTN = json_encode($BTN);
  SendFun("sendMessage?chat_id=$ChatID&parse_mode=HTML&text=".urlencode($text)."&reply_markup=$BTN");
}``` The function has what you say

Comment: does it send the text but without the keyboard?

Comment: No, the keyboard works the problem is that when I press this button it doesn't party the query

Comment: then you need to find a way to handle the update

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: put `file_put_contents('log.txt', print_r($update, true));` and check if it triggers the update?

Answer (score 0):

there may be 4 ways to solve this problem.
1st use code like this

```
$value = $decoded_json->data;
$value2 = $value->text;
```

Something like this.
But if this dont works then try to check if the webhook is perfectly set or not. Sometimes it happens to mee also. My code is correct but bot still not responds.
Still mot works ? Check your code if any error.
Still? Check if you site https on or not and also check the permission.
else{use another language}